# Custom Combobox Control for winforms

Tags: c#

How to create a user control combo box for win form which do not have an arrow, but with all other functionalities and properties of a combo box. Masking using text box is not what i intent.

Comment: Go through this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using `OwnerDraw` may be an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a custom combo box control is a massive task in WinForms, which can not be explained in a nutshell (I know it, because I have done it). What you have to do is to wrap a native Windows control into a .NET control. As far as I remember the native combo box does not support removal of the button, so you will have to wrap a native text box and a native list box in your control and implement the UI functionality in .net (you will need a text box, but a native combo box also uses a text box - and a button and a list).

You might want to consider using WPF as your UI framework. You have much better control over the composition of your custom controls and your task should be much easier to achieve.

And of course you can look for third-party component libraries that have what you need.